# Making Data Tables Accessible for Screenreaders to read column header for each row

Tags: html

I need to revise a website to make it more accessible for users with screen readers. The biggest problem I'm running into is with data we have displayed in tables. Say the table is like this:

```
A | B | C
---------
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
```

You would want it to be read as `"A1,B2,C3,A4,B5,C6"`. Currently I'm using JAWS and it would read it as `"A,B,C,1,2,3,4,5,6"` which makes no sense to someone actually trying to understand the information presented.
Is there any markup that can make a screenreader read the table "properly"? What should a web developer do here?

HTML:
[image: Code]

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case, I would use the `aria-label` attribute. That would give a hint to the screen reader. Please, check [this](http://web-accessibility.carnegiemuseums.org/foundations/aria/) for more info.